# In Ionic 4, trying to send token to Express route, but can't verify token is even in storage

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to send my token in my headers to my Express route, was having trouble, so I wanted to verify that the token was being set in storage.  Having trouble checking this.

authentication.service.ts

```
  login(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS}/login`, user).pipe(
      tap(async (res: AuthResponse) => {
        if (res.user) {
          console.log("res.user:" + res.user.access_token);
          await this.storage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user.access_token);
          await this.storage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.user.expires_in);
          this.authenticationState.next(true);
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

The console.log displays `undefined` for each line.  How can I verify that these values are being set in storage?

The response from the post is:
[image]

Express route:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const form_password = req.body.password;
    findUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ "message": 'Server error!', "status": '500' });
        if (!user[0]) return res.status(404).send({ "message": 'User not found!', "status": '404' });
        const result = bcrypt.compareSync(form_password, user[0].password);
        if (!result) return res.status(401).send({ "message": 'Password not valid!', "status": '401' });
        const expiresIn = 24 * 60 * 60;
        user[0].access_token = jwt.sign({ id: user[0].id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: expiresIn
        });
        res.status(200).send({ "user": user, "expires_in": expiresIn, "message": 'Success!', "status": '200' });
    });
});
```

```
console.log("res.user:" + JSON.stringify(res.user));
```

results in:

````
res.user:[{"id":1,"name":"Admin","email":"Admin@test.com","password":"$2a$10$2OaS5CyGKMSF5J8wed5W7.qyNFYrPScBM49SgU7L9MBMVF0RWxx1e","created_at":"2019-10-16T13:28:06.000Z","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTcyNDU1MTk3LCJleHAiOjE1NzI1NDE1OTd9.2eFbQ294TG6gvKUxSyaQGDBEas7ZLFT8k9H7jnpOoXQ"}]```
````

Comment: From the look of your server response, you shouldn't be trying to access `res.user.access_token` but `res.access_token`…

Comment: My Express code

`res.status(200).send({ "user": user, "access_token": accessToken, "expires_in": expiresIn, "message": 'Success!', "status": '200' });
`

Comment: @baumli your code shown confirms that res.user property exists (since console.log gets called), but that res.user.access_token is not defined. I agree with Will Alex - your object returned from server has different data shape. Can you share you AuthResponse interface?

Comment: auth-response.ts
`user: {
        id: number,
        name: string,
        email: string,
        access_token: string,
        expires_in: number,
        message: any,
        status: any
    }`

Comment: Updated question code to reflect putting the access_token inside the user array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,  because I was sending the user[] array, I had to check res.user as an array.

```
          await this.storage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user[0].access_token);
          await this.storage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.user[0].expires_in);
```

Once I did that, it worked!